# How Can i find Docker Elasticserach log4j version

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, log4j

i am using elasticsearch:6.8.1 how Can i find Docker Elasticserach log4j version ? Please help me . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go on [mvnrepository for elasticsearch](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.8.1)

Which will give you the version `2.11.1`